# Bootstrap 3 Manipulating Grid Multiple rows

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

This is my HTML code :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/274x175">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/274x175">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/274x175">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x600">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/274x175">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/274x175">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/274x175">
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

This is the output :

https://jsfiddle.net/bnxxkLzv/

After the right banner that has height of 600 pixels , second row is starting. What i want to achieve is to make second row start below the first on the **left** to 300x600 banner , by lets say some fixed margin of `15px` . How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea how to stack 2 rows side by side

Design the page as columns and it will be easy to stack it side by side just like nested columns

Look at this [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/bhavuksuthar/wcjz0f2v/1/)

To add `margin` you can declare a class wherever you deem fit and give property value

Comment: Well done sir, you answered my question. And just now i realised i haven't phrased it correctly. 
I wanted that second row to appear **below** first row and next to 300x600 banner on the **left** not right. 
Again , thank for your time pointing this out , it will serve as insight either way , on to rephrase original question.

Comment: @sutekh thats easy. Use the column method and it will be side by side. place those 6 images in first column and 300X600 image in second column and you are done.

Comment: @sutekh I have updated the answer. Let me know if that answers your question or not

Comment: Thank you  , that what i needed!

Comment: I came to similiar conclusion , but i used 9+3 and 3 in each individual container , btw what is the difference between `container` and `container-fluid` in this example ?

Comment: @sutekh look at this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_stacked_to_horizontal.asp) and you will understand the difference